# Can I recover my deleted account

Tags: discussion

I was a community member since a while and decided to delete my account once. Then I came back with the same email but I lost all my reputations even that my Q/A and comments are still available under the user : user61928

Can I recover my old account and merge it my new one? (recover my Q/A,reputations,badges...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's a reason we don't recommend people delete their accounts. Once they're gone, they are gone.

Welcome back!

Comment: can you post an official link that says so

Comment: @kamil http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account: interesting part: *User deletion is irreversible.* ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213176/213575))

Comment: We also say it's impossible to reverse a bounty. There are a few discretionary truths in the system.

Comment: @Oli they can *try* but there's always the possibility that something get lost in the process. (thinking about someone that tried to undelete their account that I know)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it's impossible. All the data is there (under an anonymised account) but it's still there. I can't see a technical reason why that zombie account couldn't be revived.

However, it might be a huge pain. It's certainly not a mechanism that we moderators have. I'm asking in the Stack Exchange moderator-only chat room to see if anybody can help you out but in the meanwhile, I'd suggest using the contact link at the bottom of the page.

Plead your case and see what happens.

Comment: Should I make a feature request?

Comment: In the footer of any SE site there's a "[contact us](http://meta.askubuntu.com/contact)" link. That'll put you in touch with SE staff directly.